# Classes on button click not coming off all at once

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an admin users table on a web app I'm building, and I want the admins to be able to make other people admins, validate, and delete accounts. But to make it mobile friendly, I want to hide two columns on mobile, but also provide a button for the user with the option of seeing everything if they want to. The issue is, it takes three button pushes to reveal the whole table (when it should only be one), and the button won't let me reverse the action. Here is the JS code:

```js
  const showTable = document.getElementById("showTable");
    
     showTable.addEventListener("click", function() {
      const hiddens = document.getElementsByClassName("tableHide");
      for (h of hiddens) {
       if (h.classList.contains("tableHide")) {
        h.classList.remove("tableHide");
        showTable.innerText = "Hide Table";
       } else {
        h.classList.add("tableHide");
       }
      }
     });
```

```css
.tableHide {
        display: none;
    }
```

```html
    <button type='button' id='showTable'>Show Table</button>
    <table>
    <thead>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th class='tableHide'>Last Name</th>
    <th class='tableHide'>Username</th>
    <th>Validated</th>
    <th>Admin</th>
    <th></th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr id='1'>
    <td>Joe</td>
    <td class='tableHide'>Bob</td>
    <td class='tableHide'>joebob@gmail.com</td>
    <td><input type='checkbox' id='validated'><label for='validated'></label></td>
    <td><input type='checkbox' id='isadmin'><label for='isadmin'></label></td>
    <td class='delButCont'><button type='button' class='deleteButtons'>Delete</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id='2'>
    <td>Bob</td>
    <td class='tableHide'>Joe</td>
    <td class='tableHide'>bobjoe@gmail.com</td>
    <td><input type='checkbox' id='validated'><label for='validated'></label></td>
    <td><input type='checkbox' id='isadmin'><label for='isadmin'></label></td>
    <td class='delButCont'><button type='button' class='deleteButtons'>Delete</button></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

And a working JS fiddle with the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/7oh6rch3/1/

Where did I mess up in my logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake was the way you selected the HTML Elements and the way you assigned / removed the CSS classes. I'd use two css classes to solve this:

```js
 const showTable = document.getElementById("showTable");
 showTable.addEventListener("click", function() {
  const hiddens = document.getElementsByClassName("tableHide");
  for (h of hiddens) {
   if (h.classList.contains("mobile")) {
    h.classList.remove("mobile");
    showTable.innerText = "Hide Table";
   } else {
    h.classList.add("mobile");
   }
  }
    this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML == 'Show Table' ? 'Hide Table' : 'Show Table';
 })
```

```css
.mobile
{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<button type='button' id='showTable'>Show Table</button>
<table>
<thead>
<th>First Name</th>
<th class='tableHide mobile'>Last Name</th>
<th class='tableHide mobile'>Username</th>
<th>Validated</th>
<th>Admin</th>
<th></th>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr id='1'>
<td>Joe</td>
<td class='tableHide  mobile'>Bob</td>
<td class='tableHide  mobile'>joebob@gmail.com</td>
<td><input type='checkbox' id='validated'><label for='validated'></label></td>
<td><input type='checkbox' id='isadmin'><label for='isadmin'></label></td>
<td class='delButCont'><button type='button' class='deleteButtons'>Delete</button></td>
</tr>
<tr id='2'>
<td>Bob</td>
<td class='tableHide mobile'>Joe</td>
<td class='tableHide mobile'>bobjoe@gmail.com</td>
<td><input type='checkbox' id='validated'><label for='validated'></label></td>
<td><input type='checkbox' id='isadmin'><label for='isadmin'></label></td>
<td class='delButCont'><button type='button' class='deleteButtons'>Delete</button></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

also updated your fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/7oh6rch3/2/

Comment: So the toggling works perfectly, the only problem is, it starts in the position of showing all of the columns, I need it to start the other way around, and if I keep both classes with display:none, it will always not be displayed

Comment: edited the code snippet, now it starts with the small table

Comment: That works beautifully, I'm going to have to remember that about the live collection!!

Answer (score 1):

That's because the result of `document.querySelectorAll` is a `live` collection, so every time you remove the class `tableHide` from an element - it is also removed from the collection, which makes `for` skip an additional element.

You could copy the elements to an array to preserve the result of selection (to make it no `live`):

```
const hiddens = [...document.getElementsByClassName("tableHide")];
```